# OwnsJournal breaks UriMapper

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, navigation

If I use the OwnsJournal option for JournalOwnership, the UriMapping stops working, as in only /Views/Main.xaml will be shown even if the uri matches the id/{guid} format.  Anyone run into this?

```
<Grid x:Name="root" Background="White">
    <navigation:Frame JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal">
        <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
            <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="id/{guid}" MappedUri="/Views/Redirector.xaml?id={guid}" />
                <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/Main.xaml" />
            </uriMapper:UriMapper>
        </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
    </navigation:Frame>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `Frame.JournalOwnership` to `OwnsJournal` basicly disables frame responding to UriMapping rules, it can be used when you have multiple frames in single application, you choose a main frame that will be responding to uri mapping rules, and the rest should maintain their own journal, so you set `OwnsJournal` for them.

Otherwise all frames would be responding to URL and if you had 3 frames in single application displayed, each would navigate independently to same view, which is not desired behaviour.

Once frame has `OwnsJournal` property , only way to navigate it is from code by calling `Navigate` method.

If you want `Frame` to respond to URL changes, you need to leave its JournalOwnership at `Automatic`